# adding characters to string vb.net

Tags: arrays, database, vb.net, string

The ending of the student name should read "2016". Is this the best way to modify the string:

```
            Dim Student As String 
            If Student.Substring(0, 8) = "JoeBlogs" Then
                stg = Student.Insert(0, 3)("2016") 
            End If
```

I want the string to read "Joe2016Blogs"

Comment: `Student = Student & "2016"` which could be shortened to `Student += "2016"`

Comment: Your `Insert` method is going to do the job for the question you posed, but it is not the best solution in most cases. Fabio's answer gives you several better options.

Comment: The edited version of your question makes no sense. You say 'the ending of the student name should read "2016"' but you want "JoeBlogs" to be changed to "Joe2016Blogs". What is the rule here? Is "2016" supposed to be inserted before the second uppercase letter? What happens if there are several uppercase letters (e.g. "JoeFredBlogs") or none (e.g. "joeblogs")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend following the advice in [Fabio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40620116/1620916), however, to answer your specific question, you can do the following:

```
Dim Student As String  = "JoeBlogs"
If Student.Substring(0) = "JoeBlogs" Then
    Dim stg as string = Student.Insert(3, "2016")
    console.WriteLine(stg)
End If
```

Which produces the following:

> Joe2016Blogs

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation should be avoided when done many thousands of times, but for something quick the following will do it: `stg = Student & "2016"`

Comment: so what if you were adding it to a random position in the string like so?

Answer (score 0):

String type is immutable, so in any case you need to create new string.
You can use concatenation

```
Dim newValue As String = stringVariable + "2016" + anotherStringVariable
```

or you can use `String.Format` method

```
Dim newValue As String = String.Format("{0}2016{1}", firstValue, secondValue);
```

In VB.NET 14 you can use more readable string interpolation feature

```
Dim newValue As String = $"{first}2016{second}"
```

And if you creating string in the loops with unknown amount of variables use `StringBuilder`

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each item As String in stringCollection
    builder.Append(item)
    builder.Append("2016")
End For
Dim allItems As String = builder.ToString()
```

In your case main problem is to split "JoeBlog" to the name and "blog" word and then put "2016" between